# How are quarter-precision motion vectors encoded

Tags: video-encoding, hevc

I would need to understand how exactly motion vectors are encoded, for non integer precision (whether it is for quarter pel, 1/16 pel or whatever)

In the code, the motion vectors components are always integers, but I don't understand how to deal with non integer precision.

For example if my motion vector "actual values" are say (3.5, 2.75), how then to get the "int" values that are in the code, or if the value of the x and y component in the code are (114, 82) and it is with quarter pel precision, what are the actual values ?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

They are basically scaled to integer and then coded. For instance, `MV=2.75` is scaled to `scaledMV=2.75x4=11`. Note that to be able to decode integer MVs, they should be scaled, too. For instance, `MV=1.0` will become `scaledMV=4x1.0=4.0`.

FYI, the MV coding of HEVC is way too complicated to be explained here. So, I would suggest that you take a look at [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/76/4358651/06316136.pdf) paper.